# (PY) Error Message : cannot import name 'pkcs1_15'

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, signature, pkcs#1

I'm studying about RSA encryption & decryption, so that I should import several packages related with it like the below, but one of them can't be imported.

```
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256 as SHA
```

It answered an error message like `cannot import name 'pkcs1_15'`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem faced. 
try this :

```
pip3 install cryptodome
```

Comment: pip3 install pycryptodome works (pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html) –

Answer (score 1):

If you get "cryptodome" is not in the npm registry or "pycryptodome" is not in the npm registry

You can try
pip install pycrypto mode
or
pip install "pycryptodome==3.9.7" (specific version)

Comment: pip3 install pycryptodome works (https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html)